# ComboBox in JavaFX application doesn't show the data

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I have class:

```
public class Element {
    private final IntegerProperty id;
    private final StringProperty name;

    ...constructors...

    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }
```

And I try to display List of those elements in ComboBox. In my controller I have:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<Element> combo;
```

And then I have following code in function that fill other GUI elements:

```
ObservableList<Element> elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ElRep.getElements());
combo = new ComboBox<Element>(elements);
combo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

I also tried:

```
combo.setItems(elements);
```

and nothing seems to work. I get empty ComboBox.

Comment: There are several questions on here like this; I can't find them with a quick search right now. But ***do not initialize `@FXML`-annotated fields***. I.e. remove the line `combo = new ComboBox<>(...)`. You are creating a new combo box (i.e. not the one you defined in the FXML file) and setting the items on it, instead of the one you created in FXML.

Comment: Then my combo variable is set to null and I get NullPointerException even though fx:id of my ComboBox is set.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. But "fixing" it by creating a new combo box is definitely not going to work. [Edit] your question to show a [MCVE], with a minimal controller and FXML file.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** initialize fields annotated `@FXML`: the point of that annotation is that the object is created as part of loading the FXML file and is injected into the controller. If you create a new object, you will no longer be referencing the object created by the FXML loader (and displayed in the UI): so any changes you make to that object's properties will not appear in the UI.

So omit the call to `new ComboBox<>(...)` and use `combo.setItems(...)` (or `combo.getItems().setAll(...)`) to initialize the existing combo box:

Example controller:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public class Controller {


    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Element> combo ;

    public void initialize() {
        ObservableList<Element> elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Element(1, "Element 1"),
            new Element(2, "Element 2")
        );

        combo.setItems(elements);
        combo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }
}
```

FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    <top>
        <ComboBox fx:id="combo" />
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Test:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]